# Print spills out when trying to print progress bar with '\r' in python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a simple progress bar in python, with '\r' and end='':

```
In [1]: for i in range(100):
...:        print("\rUploading some sort of data: ", i, "/", 100, end='')
...:        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The expected out would be like:

```
Uploading some sort of data:  99 / 100
```

But it now gives me this:

```
Uploading some sort of data:  99 / 100/ 100 100100
```

(I am using Spyder and I am not encountering this issue with windows command, is it the problem of Spyder? and how should I solve this?)

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce the bug, Spyder console just works fine with your code both as script and as IPython cell. Latest spyder on Mac, Python 3.7.2. Maybe it's specific to the Windows version?

Comment: It seems clear that some of the 98 first lines are writing up to 12 extra characters, so I'd suggest temporarily changing `\r` into `\n` to keep all the lines on screen instead of overwriting them every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just accidently succeed to figured out the issue by myself.

For unknown reasons, the ipython console in Spyder handles the print operation **uncorrectly** with **comma**, but **correctly** with **placeholders** or **{}.format()**:

[image]

Thanks all!